# Create formatted excel file from PL/SQL

Tags: excel, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I'm trying to create excel file formatted like this:

[image]

I tried to use https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:769425837805, but it is good for putting ONLY simple table in report - I need data like Info1/2/3 etc.
I tried csv, sperated by ';', but that makes excel unformatted, and it is unreadable.
Any ideas?

PS If there is a way to paint cell - great, but if not - it isn't necessary.

PS2 2nd thought - column number in bottom part of raport varies between diffrent input data. So that makes tool from link useless

Comment: What is the actual ussie: layout, serialization to CSV or anything else? Obviously there's no any code that may be given an instruction "do it like that" and it will produce the output you need. You **have to** customize something for custom solution, but it is not clear what customization is your current concern.

Comment: The issue is formatting "I'm trying to create excel file looking like this" - mayby it's not enough explained

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the following tzwo options:

1. Free as part the Alexandria tools: https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils/blob/master/ora/xlsx_builder_pkg.pkb
2. Commercial option: https://www.oraexcel.com